# add a clickable text link in toolbar android but not working

Tags: android

I would like to add a text with clickable link in toolbar ,

string setting :

```
<string name="q4"><a href="http://google.com/">news</a></string>
```

toolbar.xml setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/q4"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

it can show the "news" word, but I can't click it to google.. how can I make it click to google ? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Java code.All you need to do is give the title TextView an id, retrieve the TextView in your activity or fragment, and then call the following:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.q4)));
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: don't  know how to use..sorry

Comment: @LilyWong you need to set an id in xml on your textView using "android:id='@+id/your_id'", and then get a reference to it in your java code using findViewById(R.id.your_id)

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:autoLink="web" in xml and provide click for the text view which navigates to the url using Action view intent.